# Ruby: Are singleton classes really own anonymous classes?

Tags: ruby, singleton

In the chapter *24.2 Singletons* of the book *Programming Ruby 1.9 & 2.0*, the following code is given:

```
animal = "cat"
def animal.speak
  puts "The #{self} says miaow"
end
```

And explained as: "When we defined the singleton method for the "**cat**" object, Ruby created a new anonymous class and defined the **speak** method in that class. This anonymous class is called a *singleton class* (and sometimes an *eigenclass*)."

Unfortunately, I cannot verify that Ruby (2.5.1) actually creates an own anonymous class:

```
str = "a string"                 # => "a string"
[str, str.object_id]             # => ["a string", 47279316765840]
[str.class, str.class.object_id] # => [String, 47279301115420]

def str.greet
  "hello"
end                              # => :greet

str.greet                        # => "hello"

[str, str.object_id]             # => ["a string", 47279316765840]
[str.class, str.class.object_id] # => [String, 47279301115420]
```

As can be seen above, the class of *str* does not change after defining the singleton method *greet* : it is still shown as *String* with the same object_id 47279301115420.

So, where is the anonymous class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "a string"                 # => "a string"
[str, str.object_id]             # => ["a string", 47279316765840]
[str.class, str.class.object_id] # => [String, 47279301115420]

def str.greet
  "hello"
end                              # => :greet

str.greet                        # => "hello"
```

Ruby hides the *eigenclass* when you ask `str.class` or look the ancestory chain (`str.class.ancestors`). You can however get the reference to eigenclass by returning self after inspecting in it's class using `<<`

```
str_class = class << str
  self
end
# => #<Class:#<String:0x007fbba28b3f20>>

str_class.instance_methods(false) #=> [:greet] # the singleton method you defined becomes the instance method of this eigenclass. :)

str_class.ancestors
[#<Class:#<String:0x007fbba28b3f20>>, String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: Thx. Surprisingly, the hex string in the to_s representation of str_class ("#Class:#<String:0x...>>") is neither equal to str_class.object_id nor to str.object_id. Any idea which object_id is the hex string?